# CentOS packet capture device

Tags: centos, iptables, ip, nat, forwarding

I want to build a packet capture device for my home network (testing purposes). I have a spare computer with one NIC. I have CentOS. I've used TCPDump before so I plan on using that for now to see network traffic.

The issue is config. I have enabled IP forwarding:
http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/

Now seeing I do have a modem/router combo (from ATT), I would rather not deal with that aka thats why I'm doing this project, how can I  get ALL NETWORK traffic to pass through the packet capture device? NAT? Make it look like a router? If so, what are the iptable commands?

I believe this is the last part of my project, so any help would be great!

Comment: use `-j TEE` target. http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html

Comment: Could you provide a example please. I'm not that familiar with iptables for NAT?

Comment: After reading about TEE it sounds like it just forwards a packet to what you  mention as a gateway (Dest). Not sure not that would help me? Would IP forwarding bring all traffic in and I would use TEE to forward it to the router/modem?